# Installing Software, How to Find Unix Socket

Tags: postgresql, sockets, unix

I'm in the process of installing a program called Moodle onto our server. During the installation process it asked for the Database port and Unix socket for the PostgreSQL database.

I found the database port with a sql command but I don't know how to find the Unix socket.

I'm vaguely familiar with the concept from my Unix classes but I don't know too much about this.

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The location for the unix domain socket will be configured in the postgresl.conf file.

eg:

```
unix_socket_directories = '/run/postgresql'
```

The name of the socket will be the same as the TCP port number, same config file.

eg:

```
port = 5432
```

So, here the socket is at `/run/postgresql/5432`